# linux command "tail -f filename" doesnt work

Tags: linux, file, operating-system, tail

I use `tail -f filename` monitoring a text file,and use `vi` editor adding a line at the end of the file.

But after saving the file I did not see the update on the terminal which '`tail -f`' are monitoring.

What is the problem? Is `vi` editor has buffer or something?

Comment: How much text are you adding with vi? It might not be vi, it might be the OS buffering.

Comment: try to `echo`, or `cat` text to the end instead. Vim actually writes a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vi/vim copy the file to a temporary file, vis:

`[root@mg ~]# lsof | grep temp3
tail      29146    root    3r      REG    253,0     2474    2228230 /root/temp3
vim       29260    root    4u      REG    253,0    12288    2228273 /root/.temp3.swp`

So the file you're tailing is listed there, and the .temp3.swp vim has created as well.

Once you save the file, vim deletes the original and renames the .temp3.swp file to temp3.swp

lsof will show you're tailing a deleted file:

`[root@mg ~]# lsof | grep temp3
tail      29146    root    3r      REG    253,0     2474    2228230 /root/temp3~ (deleted)`

stat will show you the new file has the inode of the .temp3.swp file above:

`[root@mg ~]# stat temp3
  File: 'temp3'
  Size: 2482            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 2228273     Links: 1`